# Help me to understand the simplifications

Tags: factorial

I have trouble understanding the 8/9 step when they switch the denominators after converting the division to a multiplication, the step after the equal sign (when the 1! and 7! becomes 7! and 1!) also in the step 9/9 why there is a factorial of 3 posibilities (7* 6* 5) now instead of 4 possibilities (7*6*5*4) like in the main question?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/AXdpD]

(couldn't add a proper image markup due to no reputation, but this questions has no point without the image)

Comment: If you are asking why we could exchange the $7!$ and the $1!$, note that for any $a,b,x,y$ we have $\frac{a}{b}\cdot \frac{x}{y}=\frac{a\cdot x}{b\cdot y}=\frac{a\cdot x}{y\cdot b}=\frac{a}{y}\cdot\frac{x}{b}$.  This follows by definition of multiplication of fractions, commutativity of multiplication, and associativity of multiplication.

Comment: If you are asking why we could convert $\frac{\frac{5!}{1!}}{\frac{7!}{3!}}$ to $(\frac{5!}{1!})(\frac{3!}{7!})$, note that $\frac{a}{b}=a\cdot b^{-1}$ and that $(\frac{x}{y})^{-1}=\frac{y}{x}$.  That is to say, division is the same as multiplying by the multiplicative inverse and that the multiplicative inverse of a (*nonzero*) fraction is the fraction flipped upside down.

Comment: @JMoravitz I feel so dumb now, it was so obvious, I was thinking about division all the time instead, thanks, and why suddenly the factorial reduces by 3 possibilities in the last point? Couldn't understand that one yet

Comment: $7!=7\cdot (6!)=7\cdot 6\cdot (5!)=7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot (4!)=\dots=7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$  In general $n!=n\cdot (n-1)!$.  They did this so that both the numerator and denominator could be seen as multiples of $5!$.  Once that was seen, they could cancel the common factor.  Remember that $\frac{ax}{bx}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{x}{x}=\frac{a}{b}\cdot 1=\frac{a}{b}$ (*for nonzero $x$*).  As such $\frac{5!}{7!}=\frac{5!}{7\cdot6\cdot (5!)}=\frac{1}{7\cdot 6}$

Comment: @JMoravitz btw, didn't understand why in your second answer when we switch the division to a multiplication there is a (-1), (a*b -1) what does the (-1) means there?

Comment: the -1 there is intended as a superscript and represents the multiplicative inverse.  Given some $ a $ the number $ a^{-1}$ is the unique number such that $ a\cdot a^{-1}=1$.  For example $2^{-1}=0.5$ since $2\cdot 0.5=1$

Answer (score 0):

We can do this question in a simple way. 
Choose 1st child. $P(boy)=\frac{5}{7}$ because 5 boys and 2 girls.
Now choose 2nd child. $P(boy)=\frac{4}{6}$ because 4 boys and 2 girls.
Similarly, third and fourth student. We will get $\frac{3}{5}$ and $\frac{2}{4}$ respectively. 
$\frac{5}{7}*\frac{4}{6}*\frac{3}{5}*\frac{2}{4}=\frac{1}{7}$.

Comment: `\cdot` or `\times` for multiplication instead of `*` looks much cleaner.  `*` is used for other purposes.  As for the content of your answer, although I agree that this might be a potentially cleaner way to arrive at the answer to the question in the image, the question asked by the OP was about how the specific simplifications were made... not how to answer the question in the image.